# Read more в тексте на нативном html (не через button)

Tags: html, button, text

Как на нативном `html` сделать в тексте *Read more* и получить развернутый блок?

Вот  что я имею ввиду.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>No hidden charges</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">read more</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    No surprises or additional payments above agreed costs
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: главное чтобы не был bootstrap. он портит весь сайт из за того что с начало загружается мои настройки css ... а потом bootstrap, и выходит что bootstrap повыше моего и портит всё

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял:
лучше всего сделайте это на jquery

```
#demo{display:none}

$('element').click(function(){
$('#demo').slideToggle();
});
```

чтобы открывался ближайший read more пробуйте переписать 2-ую строку скрипта с использование метода `next` или `closest`

[документация](https://jquery-docs.ru/slideToggle/examples/)

Однако можно на чистом `css` через `checkbox` или `target`

Comment: а какой код нужно для чистый css через checkbox или target

Comment: <input type="checkbox">
<div id="demo">тут большой текст</div>


#demo {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + #demo {
  display: block;
}  далее нужно стилизовать чекбокс

Comment: http://gering111.com/target-css/ http://gering111.com/target-css/